# Laravel 7.4: Cant upload logo on server

Tags: laravel

I set this up as follows.
It works perfectly fine on a localhost setup, but doing it through Client Server, it fails to upload the image or logo.
What am I missing here?

**UploadFileController.php**

```
public function uploadLogo(Request $request) {

    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($user) {
       
        $file = $request->file;
        $publicPath = public_path();
        $path = $publicPath.'\img\logo.png';

        if (File::exists($path)) {
            File::delete($path);                
        }

        $path = $request->file->storeAs('img', 'logo.png', 'logo');
        return 'saved';
    }

}
```

**filesystems.php**

```
    'logo' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path(),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: Whats the size of the image/logo ? cause it might have to do with the php.ini configs:
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 21M

Comment: Have you checked permissions for the path? Whether the `www-data` - web server user has write permissions on folder `public/img` on the client server

Comment: Permissions are fine yes, but I would need to check the file size in .ini.

Comment: @MarwaneEzzaze the settings are way above that. on 256m

Answer (score 0):

in laravel you have to create link to your storage folder in public folder using this command, then you can see images,

`php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one I always use like this

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$filepath = public_path().'/img/';
$filename = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
$image->move($filepath, $filename);
```